# Access to files on a windows shared folder over network

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to access to a file (ex: pdf file) on a shared windows folder.
(using the FILE protocol)

```
file://myShareServer/path/to/myFile.pdf
```

jquery ajax returns :

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://myShareServer/path/to/myFile.pdf. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

how can i reach this file with jquery javascript

ps: all access to the the server are granted.
i'm using ASP.NET MVC4 on server side

EDIT: 
i'm using the PDF.JS library to runder pdf files (the problem is here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat it like any other file on your computer and make it a link as links don't have a cross origin policy like XMLHttpRequests.

```
<a href="file://myShareServer/path/to/myFile.pdf">Download the file</a>
```

Comment: thanks Hexxagonal, i cant use this solution, i'm using the PDF.JS library to runder pdf files,

Comment: Ok, then make a jsonp request for the binary data and have your website output the PDF file.  If I get time later, I'll try to throw some code together.