# Cordova app - Create file in windows/mac shared folder

Tags: cordova, networking, webpack, shared-directory

I've a cordova application and I would like to send a file from my device to my PC, both are over the same local network. On my windows PC I shared a folder and I know the cordova-plugin-file but I don't know how I can write/create a file in windows shared folder from my Cordova app.

For example, I've installed Solid Explorer File Manager (android app) in my device and I can see the network drives and therefore my windows shared folder, but I do not know how he does it.

Any help will be too appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that can be done with Cordova, since it only allow you to build hybrid apps. Solid Explorer File Manager was build with pure java and the android SDK.

Comment: Yes, I know, I downloaded the apk and I saw that its code is java but is there any way to do it with javascript? 

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930983/access-to-files-on-a-windows-shared-folder-over-network

Comment: Hi Yacine, that solution is for get a file from my windows shared folder but I need to write a file there.
Thanks.